# Understanding code in transition.js bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw the below code in [transition.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/transition.js), which is part of bootstrap:

```
  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I understand how this works and I even tested this in Mozilla, the result I get in the console is as follows :

```
Object { end: "transitionend" }
```

I believe in different browsers the result will be different. Can somebody tell me when the condition `if (el.style[name] !== undefined)` passes or fails?

Also why the `return false` in the end, it says only for I.E 8, but can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Here's the pull request for the IE 8 change:  [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10283).  And the issue that started it:  [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7295)

Comment: @sarme , wow , how exactly did you get those links from ? git blame button ?

Comment: Pure detective work.  You linked to the file in git, so I went through the commit history for the file until I found the pull request that included the "return false" in question.  That's the first link.  In the notes that accompany the pull request, issue #10283 is mentioned.  That's the second link.  Just took a while to dig through it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is checking whether each of the style properties listed in `transEndEventNames` exists in the current browser and returns when it finds the first match.

WebKit based browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc) will return for the first item in the collection: `webkitTransitionEnd`.

The first 3 items in the list are vendor specific CSS properties. Those being Webkit, Mozilla and Opera. The last item in the list is the CSS standard property name as defined by W3C.

IE8 will return false because it doesn't support any of the CSS properties listed in the test object.

I believe they mention IE8 specifically because other browsers would treat a non return from a function as `undefined` which is a falsey value (If you do a boolean check against `undefined` it will be treated similarly to the value `false`). The explicit `return false` would therefore be for browsers that don't return a falsey value when no return value is specified.